# Restriction of semistable sheaf to hyperplane of cover

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety of dimension at least $2$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$ be a very ample line bundle and $E$ be a $\mu$-semistable sheaf on $X$. Then a theorem of Maruyama states if $r(E)<dim(X)$, them for general hyperplane section $H\in|\mathcal{O}_X(1)|$, the restriction $E_H$ is $\mu$-semistable.

Now, let $f:X\to \mathbb{P}^n$ be a ramified double cover (I have the quartic double solid in mind), and $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$ be $f^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(1)$ and $E$ still a $\mu$-semistable sheaf on $X$. Is there anything we can say to the stability of the restriction of $E$ to a general section $H$ of $\mathcal{O}_X(1)$?

Thanks a lot for the help!